# Get typed document from an index using Umbraco

Tags: indexing, umbraco, umbraco7, examine

### What I'll try

I've got a lot of persons inside the content tree and I'll create a new index for that. This is for improve the performance of the web application when searching for a specific person.

---

### Create the index

I've made a new index in the examine manager from Umbraco 7.7 named `PersonIndexer` to index all the persons. This includes only the node types of a person.

[image: Examine Manager from Umbraco]

For this I've made this code:

#### `ExamineSettings.config`

Inside the file `ExamineSettings.config` inside the `Examine` → `ExamineIndexProviders` → `providers` tag:

```xml
<add name="PersonsIndexer" 
     type="UmbracoExamine.UmbracoContentIndexer, UmbracoExamine" 
     supportUnpublished="false"
     supportProtected="true" 
     indexSet="Persons"
     analyzer="Lucene.Net.Analysis.WhitespaceAnalyzer, Lucene.Net"/>
```

And inside the same file I've also added this but inside the `Examine` → `ExamineSearchProviders` → `providers` tag:

```xml
<add name="PersonsSearcher" 
     type="UmbracoExamine.UmbracoExamineSearcher, UmbracoExamine" 
     supportUnpublished="false"
     supportProtected="true" 
     indexSet="Persons"
     analyzer="Lucene.Net.Analysis.WhitespaceAnalyzer, Lucene.Net"/>
```

#### `ExamineIndex.config`

Inside the file `ExamineIndex.config` inside the `ExamineLuceneIndexSets` tag:

```xml
<IndexSet SetName="Persons" IndexPath="~/App_Data/TEMP/ExamineIndexes/Persons/" >
    <IndexAttributeFields>
        <add Name="knowledge" />
        <add Name="photo" />
        <add Name="name"/>
        <add Name="firstName"/>
        <add Name="lastName"/>
    </IndexAttributeFields>

    <IncludeNodeTypes>
        <add Name="person" />
    </IncludeNodeTypes>
</IndexSet>
```

---

### Get the documents

When I build this index, it got 7 documents inside the index.

[image: After building the index]

How can I get all this documents inside my view. I've tried this code:

```csharp
var indexer = ExamineManager.Instance.IndexProviderCollection["PersonsIndexer"];
```

This gives me all properties of that index.

[image: Quick watch of the indexer variable]

---

### The question

This isn't what I need. So my question is: How could I get the typed documents from that index?

---

### Edit

After @Marks answer I've tried his code but when I watch `searchResults` I've got this:

[image: An empty list]

When I do a Lucene search of `*`, I've got 7 results.

[image: Lucene search of * gives 7 results]

When I do a text search xor I text xor lucene search on an empty string, I've got nothing.

Comment: Continued here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/176629/get-typed-results-for-examine-indexer-using-umbraco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the searcher to retrieve the documents.

Here's a little example of some code I used to retrieve documents from the index, hope it helps you.

```csharp
var searcher = ExamineManager.Instance.SearchProviderCollection["PersonsSearcher"];
var searchCriteria = searcher.CreateSearchCriteria();
var query = searchCriteria.Field("nodeTypeAlias", "person").Compile();
var searchResults = searcher.Search(query);
```

**Edit**

I've taken a look at my `ExamineIndex.config` and you'll have to define the default Umbraco properties and user defined properties seperately in the XML.

A little example of my `CustomIndexSet`.

```xml
<IndexSet SetName="CustomIndexSet" IndexPath="~/App_Data/TEMP/ExamineIndexes/Custom/">
    <IndexAttributeFields>
      <add Name="id" />
      <add Name="nodeName"/>
      <add Name="updateDate" />
      <add Name="nodeTypeAlias" />
    </IndexAttributeFields>
    <IndexUserFields>
      <add Name="category" />
      <add Name="title" />
      <add Name="description" />
      <add Name="status" />
      <add Name="keywords" />
    </IndexUserFields>
    <IncludeNodeTypes>
      <add Name="item"/>
      <add Name="category"/>
    </IncludeNodeTypes>
</IndexSet>
```

Comment: Sorry but this returns an empty list: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IAw4.png

Comment: I'm using an older Umbraco version, so maybe it's changed in the new version. Check out this documentation: https://github.com/Shazwazza/Examine/wiki/FluentSearchApi The code is slightly different

Comment: @Mark The Indexer doesn't show up in the "Examine Management" backoffice tab - using umbraco cloud project version 8. Do you have any ideas?